# what is the probability of $x = x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus ... \oplus x_n$?

Tags: probability

$P\left(x_i=0 \right)=p$ and $P\left(x_i=1 \right)=1-p$ for all $i=1:n$.

$x_i$s are i.i.d  random variables, that is, $x_i\in \{0,1 \}$.

$\oplus$ is exclusive-OR operation. That is, $0 \oplus 0= 0$, $0 \oplus 1 = 1$, $1 \oplus 0 = 1$ and $1 \oplus 1 =1$. (addition in GF (2)).

What is the probability of $P\left(x=0 \right)$ for case $n$ is even and $n$ is odd?

Finally, solved it. The answer would be $\frac{1+\left(2p-1 \right)^n}{2}$.

Comment: Is $x$ the sum of the $x_{i}$? What is an exclusive-OR operation on random variables? Or are you asking the probability that exactly one $x_{i}$ is $0$?

Comment: @aduh Given the exclusive -OR operation rules in the question.

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Comment: @aduh For $n$ is even, i think the answer is $\frac{_n\textrm{C}_0 + _n\textrm{C}_3 + ... + _n\textrm{C}_n }{2^n}$. Where C is the Binomial coefficient.

Comment: $C_i$ is the Binomial coefficient.

Comment: @VineelKumarVeludandi:  the answer clearly has to involve $p$.  For your form of binomial coefficient, the $n$ should be subscripted, too, so you should write _nC_0 to get $_nC_0$ I think n \choose 0 is preferred, giving $n \choose 0$

Comment: @RossMillikan edited as per your suggestion.

Comment: I think the answer is $\frac{_nC_0 p^0 \left( 1-p\right)^p + _nC_2 p^2\left(1-p \right)^{n-2}+...}{2}$

Comment: But how does exclusive-OR work on several variables? I would think "There are an odd number of $1$'s" is an interpretation that is just as natural as "There is exactly _one_ $1$"

Comment: @Arthur Just like $0 \oplus 0 \oplus 1 = 1$.

Comment: But what is $1\oplus1\oplus1$? What about $1\oplus1\oplus1\oplus0$?

Comment: $$\begin{align}a\oplus b=&(a\wedge \neg b)\vee(\neg a\wedge b)\\a\oplus b\oplus c=&(a\wedge b\wedge c)\vee(a\wedge\neg b\wedge\neg c)\vee(\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg c)\vee(\neg a\wedge\neg b\wedge c)\\a\oplus b\oplus c\oplus d=&{(a\wedge b\wedge c\wedge\neg d)\vee(a\wedge b\wedge\neg c\wedge d)\\\vee(a\wedge\neg b\wedge c\wedge d)\vee(\neg a\wedge b\wedge c\wedge d)\\\vee(a\wedge\neg b\wedge\neg c\wedge\neg d)\vee(\neg a\wedge b\wedge\neg c\wedge\neg d)\\\vee(\neg a\wedge\neg b\wedge c\wedge\neg d)\vee(\neg a\wedge\neg b\wedge\neg c\wedge d)}\end{align}$$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n x_i$ is odd successes.

Comment: That is: $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n x_i$ is the event of an odd count of successes among the $n$ Bernoulli variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a recurrence.  Let $Q(n)$ be the chance that $x=0$ given that there are $n\ x_i$'s.  We have $Q(1)=p$.  What is $Q(n+1)$ given $Q(n)$?  I don't find any difference between even and odd $n$, I just see convergence toward $\frac 12$

Comment: Yes, it is independent of whether $n$ is even or odd. Also, as $n$ tends to become large, $P\left(x=0 \right)$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could you please explain it how.

Comment: Yes, intuitively, the probability should converge to $1/2$. But could you tell the closed form expression as a function of $n$.

Comment: I think the closed form expression would be $\frac{_nC_0 p^0 \left(1-p \right)^p + _nC_2 p^2 \left(1-p \right)^{p-2}+ _nC_4 p^4 \left(1-p \right)^{p-4}+...}{2}$

Comment: However, I want a more tighter closed form expression.

Comment: Your expression would be correct if you didn't divide by $2$. When $p=\frac 12$ it simplifies to $\frac 12$ independent of $n$.  Otherwise, I don't know a shorter form.

Comment: Yes, dividing by 2 is not necessary like you have said. because $p$ is already probability.

Comment: Finally solved it, the closed form expression would be $\frac{1+{\left(2p-1 \right)}^n}{2}$. THANK YOU.